# not able to recover saved folder in ubuntu

Tags: directory

I am booting ubuntu using an external hard drive.But every new time I boot, I am unable to access/even see the folders I created during last boot.

Comment: What do you mean by "external hard drive" ? Have you installed Ubuntu on an external disk, or are you booting from a Live media  ?

Comment: It sounds like you are running in a 'live' environment. in the 'live' system everything is temporary and lost on reboot.  How did you install Ubuntu to your external hdd?

Comment: external disk i mean

Comment: i have installed it using universal usb installer

Comment: Follow the instructions on how to install Ubuntu properly at http://download.ubuntu.com

Comment: i guess some trouble is there with my system .it is an old machine whose bios is legacy. is there any different procedure to install for legacy bios ?